# Integration Test: how to test Navigator.pop()?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I'm testing an application using Integration Test.
In the application, on the AddGroupPage page, the user enters the name of the group, clicks on the save button, and using Navigator.pop() returns to the main page where the name of the group is displayed. How to test return to previous screen?
My Test:

```js
class MockNavigatorObserver extends Mock implements NavigatorObserver {}

    void main() {
      late NavigatorObserver mockObserver;
      IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      
      setUp(() {
        mockObserver = MockNavigatorObserver();
      });
      
      testWidgets(
  "After inputting a text, go to the display page which contains group that same text ",
  (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      BlocProvider(
        create: (_) => GroupBloc(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: const AddGroupPage(),
          navigatorObservers: [mockObserver],
        ),
      ),
    );
    const inputText = 'Group';
    await tester.enterText(
        find.byKey(
          const Key('add_group_field'),
        ),
        inputText);
    const IconData iconBtn = Icons.save;
    final saveGroupBtn = find.byIcon(iconBtn);
    await tester.tap(saveGroupBtn);
    verify(mockObserver.didPop(any, any));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(find.byType(AddGroupPage), findsNothing);
    expect(find.byType(GroupsPage), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text(inputText), findsOneWidget);
  },
);
```

I have errors on the lines where it is written verify(mockObserver.didPush(any!, any)). didPush is underlined in red and reads: This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
And also error on (any!, any): The argument type 'T Function({String? named, Matcher? that})' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Route'.

Answer (score 2):

`verify` require a Function parameter. also any is a function.

so, in your code it should be :

```
verify(() => mockObserver.didPop(any(), any());
```

and be sure to register fallback value for Route Type.

outside main :

```
class FakeRoute extends Fake implements Route {}
```

inside main :

```
registerFallbackValue(FakeRoute());
```

Comment: This works, but is there a better matcher we can use rather than `any()` to better match a specific route?